# Pyro Cms Flicker Gallery add On(from Arthur guy) Not showing the complete photosets on Front end

Tags: add-on, pyrocms

I've PyroCMS project running on my intranet, and i have used the flicker gallery from https://arthurguy.co.uk/code/pyrocms-add-on-flickr-gallery
The Back end that is admin panel showing all the photo galleries (21), but the front end of site not showing the Last two added photo galleries.
[image: Front end of Photo Gallery]

[image: Back end of Flicker gallery in admin panel]

contacted the author but he might not able to provide feed Back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through this issue, it might looks like the cache problem as this addon use the cached result as well, so first try to change the cache length from the admin panel settings and check the results.
If the problem remains there the look into the front end controller **flicker_gallery**  and check in the index function.
There is code snippent like this
 `if (! $photosets = $this->pyrocache->get('flickr_gallery_get_photosets'))`
Just remove that not `!` operator from the condition and check the results on front End. Then provide your response.

Comment: Awesome just on point, removed that check and problem resolved. thanks